# javax.el.ELException Method not found

Tags: jsf, tomcat, jsf-2, el

I am developing a web application using Primefaces JSF using managed beans in front-end and SQL Server in the back-end. I have been developing the app for 2 months, tested it in different environments in our office. By different environment I mean different java 7 versions and Tomcat 7 versions and everything has been working fine. 
Tried to continue development from my home PC and now I am getting an error

**javax.el.ELException:** /custsession_detailed.xhtml @67,122 value="#{IdToString.returnPackagetName(SearchComponent.returnCustomerProfile().packagesSegment)}": **Method not found: class al.durandal.com.jsf.IdToStringTypeComponent.returnPackagetName(java.lang.String)**

I'm 100% sure that the method is there. In both environments Java version and Tomcat versions are the same.

```
package al.durandal.com.jsf;

@ManagedBean(name="IdToString")
@ViewScoped
public class IdToStringTypeComponent extends ManagedComponent {


    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -233667982117424411L;
    private PackagesType packageType;
    private StatusType statusType;
    private static Logger logger =Logger.getLogger(IdToStringTypeComponent.class.getName());



    @Autowired
    private transient StatusTypeDAO statusTypeDAO;

    @Autowired
    private transient StatusTypeService statusTypeService;

    @Autowired
    private transient PackagesTypeDAO packagesTypeDAO;




    public List<StatusType> listAllStatusTypes(){
        return new java.util.ArrayList<StatusType>(statusTypeDAO.findAllStatusTypes());
    }

    public StatusType getStatusType() {
        return statusType;
    }



    public void setSatusType(StatusType statType) {
        this.statusType = statType;
    }

    @Transactional
    public StatusType loadStatusTypeByPrimaryKey(Integer sidKey) {
        statusType = statusTypeDAO.findStatusTypeByPrimaryKey(sidKey);

        return statusType;
    }

    public String returnProductName(Integer statusCode){


        statusType=statusTypeDAO.findStatusTypeByPrimaryKey(statusCode);
        if(statusType!=null)
        return statusType.getStatusName();
        else
            return "Empty";

    }

    public String returnPackagetName(Integer pkgCode){

        packageType =packagesTypeDAO.findPackagesTypeByIdPackage(pkgCode);

        if(packageType!=null)
            return packageType.getName();
        else
            return "Not Available";
    }


    @Override
    public void postConstruct() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        statusType= new StatusType();



    }


    public void setStatusValues(int statusId){
        System.out.println("statusId "+statusId);
        statusType = new StatusType();
        statusType = loadStatusTypeByPrimaryKey(statusId);
        System.out.println("statusType" + statusType);
        System.out.println("Ja ku jam ketu");
        setSatusType(statusType);


    }

    public int setMaxStatusType(){
        int statusTypeNo=statusTypeService.countStatusTypeMax();
        statusType = new StatusType();
        System.out.println("statusTypeNo "  +statusTypeNo);
        statusType.setSid(statusTypeNo);
        return statusTypeNo;
    }


    @Transactional
    public void saveStatusType(StatusType statustype) {

        logger.info("Saving Status Type: "+statustype.toString());
        FacesMessage message = null;
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        boolean save=false;
        try {
            //crmNotesService.saveCrmNotes(crmNotes);
            statusTypeService.saveStatusType(statustype);
            logger.info("Saving...");

            //statustype.unset();

            //statusType.setSid(statusTypeService.countStatusTypeMax());
            //
            //statustype.setSid(statusTypeService.countStatusTypes());

            save = true;


        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {   
            logger.info("FAILED during saving...");
            logger.info("Excpetions are: "+e.toString());
            throw e;
        }

     if(save) {
            message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "OK!","Saved Succesfully !");

        } else {
            message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN, "Error!", "Unable to save !");


        }
        context.addMessage(null,message );

    }


}
```

The xmthl file which is calling the function

```
<h:form style="width: auto !important;padding-top: 5px;">

                    <p:accordionPanel>                   
                        <p:tab title="#{usersmsgs['custdet.lmenu.geninfo']}">
                        <p:panelGrid columns="2" style="width:100%;">


                        <h:outputText value="#{usersmsgs['custdet.lmenu.cif']}"  />
                        <h:outputText value="#{SearchComponent.returnCustomerProfile().customerNo}" />
                        <h:outputText value="#{usersmsgs['custdet.lmenu.hostbr']}" />
                        <h:outputText value="#{SearchComponent.returnCustomerProfile().localBranch}" />
                        <h:outputText value="#{usersmsgs['custdet.lmenu.namesurn']}" />
                        <h:outputText value="#{SearchComponent.returnCustomerProfile().customerName}" />
                        <h:outputText value="#{usersmsgs['custdet.lmenu.fathname']}" />
                        <h:outputText value="#{SearchComponent.returnCustomerProfile().fatherName}" />
                        <h:outputText value="#{usersmsgs['custdet.lmenu.birthday']}" />
                        <h:outputText value="#{SearchComponent.returnCustomerProfile().birthday}" />
                        <h:outputText value="#{usersmsgs['custdet.lmenu.age']}" />
                        <h:outputText value="#{SearchComponent.returnCustomerProfile().age}" />
                        <h:outputText value="#{usersmsgs['custdet.lmenu.gender']}" />
                        <h:outputText value="#{SearchComponent.returnCustomerProfile().gender}" />
                        <h:outputText value="#{usersmsgs['custdet.lmenu.city']}" />
                        <h:outputText value="#{SearchComponent.returnCustomerProfile().city}" />
                        <h:outputText value="#{usersmsgs['custdet.lmenu.education']}" />
                        <h:outputText value="#{SearchComponent.returnCustomerProfile().education}" />
                        <h:outputText value="#{usersmsgs['custdet.lmenu.profession']}" />
                        <h:outputText value="#{SearchComponent.returnCustomerProfile().profession}" />
                        <h:outputText value="#{usersmsgs['custdet.lmenu.workcomp']}" />
                        <h:outputText value="#{SearchComponent.returnCustomerProfile().workingCompany}" />
                        </p:panelGrid>
                        </p:tab>

                        <p:tab title="#{usersmsgs['custdet.lmenu.contactinfo']}">
                        <p:panelGrid columns="2" style="width:100%;" >


                        <h:outputText value="#{usersmsgs['custdet.lmenu.address']}"  />
                        <h:outputText value="#{SearchComponent.returnCustomerProfile().address}" />
                        <h:outputText value="#{usersmsgs['custdet.lmenu.email']}" />
                        <h:outputText value="#{SearchComponent.returnCustomerProfile().email}" />
                        <h:outputText value="#{usersmsgs['custdet.lmenu.telno']}" />
                        <h:outputText value="#{SearchComponent.returnCustomerProfile().telNo}" />
                        <h:outputText value="#{usersmsgs['custdet.lmenu.mobno']}" />
                        <h:outputText value="#{SearchComponent.returnCustomerProfile().mobNo}" />
                        </p:panelGrid>
                        </p:tab>


                        <p:tab title="#{usersmsgs['custdet.lmenu.bankinfo']}">
                        <p:panelGrid columns="2" style="width: auto !important;padding-top: 2cm;padding-bottom: 70%;">


                        <h:outputText value="#{usersmsgs['custdet.lmenu.packagesSegment']}"  />
                        <h:outputText value="#{IdToString.returnPackagetName(SearchComponent.returnCustomerProfile().packagesSegment)}" />
                        <h:outputText value="#{usersmsgs['custdet.lmenu.personalincome']}" />
                        <h:outputText value="#{SearchComponent.returnCustomerProfile().personalIncome}" />
                        <h:outputText value="#{usersmsgs['custdet.lmenu.monthlysal']}" />
                        <h:outputText value="#{SearchComponent.returnCustomerProfile().monthlySalary}" />
                        <h:outputText value="#{usersmsgs['custdet.lmenu.actualexpother']}" />
                        <h:outputText value="#{SearchComponent.returnCustomerProfile().exposureOtherBanks}" />
                        <h:outputText value="#{usersmsgs['custdet.lmenu.actualexpoaba']}" />
                        <h:outputText value="#{SearchComponent.returnCustomerProfile().exposureAba}" />
                        </p:panelGrid>
                        </p:tab>

                    </p:accordionPanel>


            </h:form>
```

Comment: Method argument types are not same. Exception says it couldn't find one with String argument while your actual method only takes Integer. If this has worked before, I think you have to take a step back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this line

```
<h:outputText value="#{IdToString.returnPackagetName(SearchComponent.returnCustomerProfile().packagesSegment)}" />
```

and the log says that method being looked for accepts a **String** parameter

```
returnPackagetName(java.lang.String)
```

while the method in your bean accepts **Integer**

```
returnPackagetName(Integer pkgCode)
```